# What is a good Read, Eval, Print, Loop implementation for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono

Some programming language implementations provide a Read, Evaluate, Print Loop interactive shell to allow the programmer to evaluate expressions and program fragments, and to program in an incremental, interactive manner.

What implementations of a C# REPL have you used, and liked? It would be nice to have one that could integrate with Visual Studio as well.

I have found, but not tried, the [Mono C# REPL](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl) and [Don Box's C# REPL](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/dbox/archive/2005/05/26/8626.aspx)

Comment: see question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337254/c-console-cli-interpreter

Answer (score 5):

Mono comes with a [REPL tool called "csharp"](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl). I just tried it on Mac OS X and it works like magic. The only feature it currently lacks is Intellisense, promised to appear in Mono 2.6

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2008 includes REPL-like capabilities, though I wouldn't necessarily call them "good". I think they have the advantage of being included and always available--which can be handy when trying to do work at a workstation other than your own.

In Visual Studio, you can instantiate and invoke methods of objects using the [Object Test Bench](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3775d98(VS.80).aspx). You can also write interactive C# code (with many limits) using the [Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy(VS.80).aspx) (`Debug->View->Immediate Window`). Immediate Window can be used outside of a debugging session.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool I've found for writing interactive c# code is the [C# Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/).

Not sure if it's exactly REPL but it is a great way to test out almost anything using C#/.NET.

It supports framework versions up to 3.5.  It is not designed to integrate directly with Visual Studio, however it even provides its own intellisense.

Of course it's very easy to copy/export the code from this into your Visual Studio projects.

Answer (score 1):

One that I've only seen is at the end of [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL16/) from PDC where Hejlsberg  is going beyond C#4.

Comment: Awesome video.  The part about using the compiler as a service starts at 59 minutes and 25 seconds into the talk, but the entire video is great.  Anders is a really smart guy, and he gives a really good talk.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of an interactive shell for running c# code snippets. There is one for the mono project, but I have not tried it: http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl

I tried the C# snippet compiler, and it seems to be pretty much the same as creating a new console application in Visual Studio, but with limited intellisense, and none of the debugging features.

Right now I use the built in console application template anytime I want to try out simple input-output type experimental code. I use console Console.ReadLine() and Console.WriteLine() for input and output.

It actually works pretty well for me. I typically save all my little test programs so I can go back and find something I worked with a few months ago, and you get the full debugging features of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [VisualStudio C# REPL - O2 Platform (v5.1)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/295fa0f6-37d1-49a3-b51d-ea4741905dc2) plugin (more info at [O2Platform question on 'Interactive development with Visual Studio'](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2014/09/o2platform-question-on-interactive.html) )

There is also the stand alone version [C# REPL Script](http://blog.diniscruz.com/p/c-repl-script-environment.html) (see this readme for more details on the APIs https://github.com/o2platform/FluentSharp/blob/master/README.md )